# Graphic in Panel flashed and then disappear

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel

Recently I needed to write a program to draw a bar graph when I press a prepared place. There are two situation will draw graphic, one is press the place in the table, the other is choice the region (such as Kaohsiung or Taipei) in the typebox
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUTFL.png)

But I do not know why the press the place in the table are very clear to draw the graphic on the panel, but when I press the typebox, the drawing will flash about gone. Here are some part of my code about this issue

```
public class Google2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JPanel panel;//主要畫布
Graphics g;
int regnm=0,regns=0,regna=0,regn=0,regp=0;//生氣數量,傷心數量,憂慮數量,其他數量,正面數量
String[] stype = { "全部", "基隆", "台北", "桃園", "新竹", "苗栗", "台中", "南投", "彰化", "雲林", "嘉義"
, "台南", "高雄", "屏東", "台東", "花蓮", "宜蘭", "外島", "國外"};//所有地區
JComboBox typebox = new JComboBox(stype);//下拉式印出地區
DefaultTableModel tmc = new DefaultTableModel(new Object [][] {},new String [] { "Place","count"});//選地點用model
JTable jt =new JTable();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jt);//印出負面地點的滾輪 
public Google2(){  
    setLocation(450,50);
    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
    setSize(1300, 850);
    typebox.setBounds(125,55,125,30);add(typebox);
    typebox.addActionListener(this);
    scrollPane.setBounds(10, 90, 250, 535);add(scrollPane);
    jt.setModel(tmc);jt.setRowHeight(30);
    jt.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(//選地點
    new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
            if(!event.getValueIsAdjusting()){
                if(jt.getSelectedRow()>-1){
                    Draw();
                }                                       
            }
        }
    });     
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource()==typebox){
        Draw();
    }
}
void Draw(){
        g.setColor(WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 379, 329);
        g.setColor(BLACK);
        float lineWidth = 6.0f;
        ((Graphics2D)g).setStroke(new BasicStroke(lineWidth));
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 380, 330);
        g.setFont(font1);
        g.drawString("生氣", 30, 300);
        g.drawString("傷心", 100, 300);
        g.drawString("憂慮", 170, 300);
        g.drawString("其他", 240, 300);
        g.drawString("正面", 310, 300);
        g.setColor(RED);
        if(regnm>0){
            int md=25;
            md=md*regnm;
            if(md>250)
                md=250;
            g.fillRect(35, 275-md, 35, md);
        }            
        g.setColor(ORANGE);
        if(regns>0){
            int md=25;
            md=md*regns;
            if(md>250)
                md=250;
            g.fillRect(105, 275-md, 35, md);
        }
        g.setColor(Color.magenta);
        if(regna>0){
            int md=25;
            md=md*regna;
            if(md>250)
                md=250;
            g.fillRect(175, 275-md, 35, md);
        }
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        if(regn>0){
            int md=25;
            md=md*regn;
            if(md>250)
                md=250;
            g.fillRect(245, 275-md, 35, md);
        }
        g.setColor(BLUE);
        if(regp>0){
            int md=25;
            md=md*regp;
            if(md>250)
                md=250;
            g.fillRect(315, 275-md, 35, md);
        }
        regnm=0;regns=0;regna=0;regn=0;regp=0;       
}
//main function
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Google2 gg = new Google2();
}
}
```

I Had tried many methods like repaint, update can not be solved, there are still can be drawing when I press table, but unable drawing when I press typebox 
I hope someone can help me, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is not how painting in Swing should be done.  Start by taking a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting should be done.

Basically, you want to override the `paintComponent` method of the a component extending from something like `JComponent` (`JPanel` is generally preferred) and perform what ever custom painting you want/need to perform there, remember to call `super.paintComponent` before you do you own custom painting.

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify